# ruby build hash like quaternary number system

Tags: ruby

How to build this sequence in ruby?

```
{
"0" => "00000",
"1" => "00001",
"2" => "00002",
"3" => "00003",
"4" => "00010",
"5" => "00011",
"6" => "00012",
....
"1020" => "33330",
"1021" => "33331",
"1022" => "33332",
"1023" => "33333"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
nums = Hash.new
0.upto(1023){ |x| nums[x] = x.to_s(4) }
puts nums
```

Basically Fixnum.to_s(4) will convert your base 10 number to base 4.

**Update - As a one liner**

If you want a one liner, you can do:

```
puts (0..1023).inject({}){ |hash, e| hash[e] = e.to_s(4); hash }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = Hash.new { |h, k| "%05d" % Integer( k ).to_s( 4 ) rescue nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[1024.times.map {|n| [n.to_s, format('%05d', n.to_s(4))] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the total regularity, I don't think you should keep that as a hash. Rather you should have a method do it.

```
class String
  def quaternary
    to_i.tap{|i| return unless 0 <= i and i <= 1023}.to_s(4).rjust(5, "0")
  end
end

"5".quarternary # = > "00011"
```